# what method will call while click the cancel button in the inapppurchase?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I am developing the application with InAppPurchase.Now i have the problem,[image]

what method will call ,while click the cancel button in the above image?

anyone please help me.

Thanks advance.

Answer (score 0):

by using this method you will get the state of the transaction

```
    func paymentQueue(queue: SKPaymentQueue, updatedTransactions transactions: [SKPaymentTransaction]) {
for transaction:AnyObject in transactions {
            if let trans:SKPaymentTransaction = transaction as? SKPaymentTransaction{
                switch trans.transactionState {
                case .Purchased:
                    SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().finishTransaction(transaction as SKPaymentTransaction)
                    break;
                case .Failed:
                    SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().finishTransaction(transaction as SKPaymentTransaction)
                    break;
                    // case .Restored:
                    //[self restoreTransaction:transaction];
                default:
                   break;
                }
           }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Although this code may be help to solve the problem,
providing additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ it
answers the question would significantly improve its
long-term value.  Please [edit] your answer to add some
explanation.

Comment: while click the cancel button , in the very first time am receiving the response code. after that the cancel button is not receiving any response.